# How do I turn on IntelliSense? (VS 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have somehow managed to turn off IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2013 professional, writing in C#, I have tried a lot of keyboard combinations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>I</kbd> etc).

If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated, I have also looked at `MSDN` for an answer but haven't got one...

Comment: you could check the setting under TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->the specific language(C#) ->IntelliSense.

Comment: I have done that, it is set to Ctrl + alt + space and that didn't do anything for me :(

Comment: Then you can try reset the VS setting TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings-

Comment: I will give that a go! I shall let you know how it goes :)

Comment: That worked perfect! I cannot thank you enough for that, it was bugging me so much that I didn't have IntelliSense! Major respect for that :)

Comment: I am adding the answer to that, so that you can accept that.

Comment: I definitely will when the time lets me, thank you again :)

Comment: You can also search the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these possible cases:-

1. you could check the setting under TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->the specific language(C#) ->IntelliSense
2. you can try reset the VS setting TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings